# Good ways to integrate $\int_0^1 x^{k+1} (1-x)^k dx$?

Tags: calculus

Let $k$ be a natural number. What are some good ways to integrate
$\int_0^1 x^{k+1} (1-x)^k dx$
and
$\int_0^1 x^{k+2} (1-x)^k dx$? I wanted to use some symbolic math software but I don't have one, so I have to learn a way to do it manually. Thanks!

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251624/problem-deriving-beta-distribution-normalizing-constant

Comment: You can try http://wolframalpha.com, [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) is quite capable. [SAGE](http://sagemath.org) and [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr) are integrated ssytems.

Comment: For a very complete treatment of explicit integration methods, see the freely available 1921 book [**A Treatise on the Integral Calculus**](http://archive.org/details/treatiseonintegr01edwauoft) by Joseph Edwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $$I(a,b)=\int_0^1x^a(1-x)^bdx
$$
$$I(0,b)=\frac{1}{b+1}\quad I(a,b)=\frac{a}{b+1}I(a-1,b+1)$$
The second identity is by integrating by parts.
Solving,$$I(a,b)=\frac{a!}{(b+1)(b+2)...(b+a+1)}=\frac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!}$$
which solves the problem.

Comment: A nice check is that the final answer has to be symmetric in $a$ and $b$ as you can define $u=1-x$ and get the same integral with $a$ and $b$ interchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Hints: this is the [Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):

$$\int\limits_0^1 x^{k+1}(1-x)^k=B(k+2\,,\,k+1)=\frac{\Gamma(k+2)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(2k+3)}=\frac{(k+1)!k!}{(2k+2)!}$$