# finding the expansion of $\arcsin(z)^2$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, laurent-series

Is there a fast and nice way to find the expansion of $\arcsin(z)^2$ without squaring expansion of $\arcsin(z)$ ?

> For $|z|<1$ show that 
>   $$(\sin^{-1}(z))^2 = z^2 + \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{z^4}{2} + \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{z^6}{3}+ \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{6}{7}\cdot \frac{z^8}{4} + \dots$$

It should have something like $c_{2n} = \frac{2^{2n}n!^2}{(2n+1)!n}$ as coefficient maybe we could use Residue theorem to evaluate it.

Comment: A result of Euler : $$2\;\arcsin(x)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}$$ from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319437/limit-of-series-involving-ratio-of-two-factorials) (without proof)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prove that the formula :

$$2\;\arcsin(x)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}$$

is right we may use the method proposed by the brothers Borwein at the end of 'Pi and the AGM'.

Observe that :
$$x \frac{d}{dx}(\arcsin\ x)^2=\frac{2x \arcsin\ x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
and use the fact that both $\ \displaystyle f(x)= \frac{\arcsin\ x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ $ and $\ \displaystyle F(x)=\frac{1}{2x}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^{2m}}{m\binom{2m}{m}}$

satisfy the differential equation : $\;(1-x^2)f'=1+xf$

From $f(0)=F(0)$ me may then integrate relatively to $x$ (under the sum sign) $\;f(x)=F(x)\;$ to get (the $2x$ at the denominator disappears and a $2m$ appears) :
$$\arcsin(x)^2=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2m}\frac{(2x)^{2m}}{m\binom{2m}{m}}$$

(this was stolen from my [earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99809/how-to-prove-by-arithmetical-means-that-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frack-1/99941#99941) with better references... [robjohn's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99809/how-to-prove-by-arithmetical-means-that-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frack-1/128680#128680) in that link should be helpful too (+1) !)

For alternative proofs of the expansion of $\arcsin(x)^2$ and many other functions you may consult this [table](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Reihenentwicklungen#4.3) (3 proofs are exposed by clicking on 'Ausklappen' at the right). The first proof for the [expansion](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Reihenentwicklungen#4.2) of the derivative for example uses $\,\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac {\pi}2} \sin^{2n-1}\theta\ d\theta=\frac{2^{2n-1}}{n\binom{2n}{n}}$.

(from [joriki's nice answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120282/residue-of-z2-e1-sin-z-at-z-pi/120450#120450) where the coefficients of $x^{-n}\,$ in $\;e^{-\frac 1{\sin(x)}}$ were given using the expansions of $\arcsin(x)^n$ for $n=1,2,3$)

Expansions of higher powers of $\arcsin(x)^n$ may be found too in the [table](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Reihenentwicklungen#4.4) or in Mhenni's answer here (in terms of gamma and [polygamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) functions $\psi^{(n)}$ up to $n=6$).

Comment: I was expecting complex analytic method. If I find it ... i'll let you know.

Comment: @MonkeyD.Luffy: Thanks it should be interesting (but doesn't appear really easy...)

Answer (score 6):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307274/how-can-i-prove-my-conjecture-for-the-coefficients-in-tx-log1-expx/308100#308100). It seems we can go beyond this. Here is the Taylor series expansion of $ \arcsin(x)^3 $

> $$\arcsin(x)^3 = \frac{3}{4\sqrt {\pi }}\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }\,{\frac { \left( {\pi }^{2}-2\,\psi'\left( 
> m+\frac{1}{2} \right)  \right) \Gamma\left( m+\frac{1}{2} \right) {x}^{2\,m+1}}{
> \left( 2\,m+1 \right) \Gamma  \left( m+1 \right) }}.$$

**Added:** Here is the requested series

> $$ \frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty}{\frac {\Gamma  \left( m+1
>  \right)\, {x}^{2\,m+1}}{\Gamma  \left( m+\frac{3}{2} \right) }}.$$

**Added:** Here are the power series of $\arcsin(x)^4$ and $\arcsin(x)^6$ respectively

> $$ \frac{\sqrt {\pi }}{4}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty}\,{\frac { \left( {\pi }^{2}-6\,
> \psi' \left( m+1 \right)\right) \Gamma  \left( m+1\right){x}^{2\,
> m+2}}{ \left( m+1 \right) \Gamma  \left( m+\frac{3}{2} \right) }},$$

---

> $$\frac{3\sqrt {\pi }}{32} \sum _{m=0}^{\infty }{}\,{\frac { \left( 60\,
> \left( \psi' \left( m+1 \right)  \right) ^{2}-20\,\psi' \left( m+1
> \right) {\pi }^{2}+{\pi }^{4}+10\,\psi''' \left( m+1 \right)  \right) 
> \Gamma  \left( m+1 \right) {x}^{2\,m+2}}{ \left( m+1 \right) \Gamma\left( m+\frac{3}{2} \right) }}.$$

Comment: Hi ... can we find the n-th derivative of $\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Comment: You want to use integral approach to the problem.

Comment: yes i want to calculate the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{\arcsin(z)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}z^{n+1}}dz$

Comment: @MonkeyD.Luffy: I posted the series you requested.

Comment: could you give me link of proof of that?

Comment: Try to prove it using the product of two series and using the Cauchy product formula $ \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ib_{n-1} $.

Comment: cauchy product of which sequence??

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: You are very welcome.

Comment: @Raymond (and Mhenni): see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/120450), where I use the series for $\arcsin^3 x$ given [here](https://oeis.org/A001824).

Comment: @joriki: I just added new identities. Can you check them?

Comment: @Mhenni: I checked them numerically (to $65$ digits) both seem right.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: Thanks for doing that. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer is

**Theorem 1.**
For $m\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dotsc\}$ and $|t|<1$, the function $\bigl(\frac{\arcsin t}{t}\bigr)^{m}$, whose value at $t=0$ is defined to be $1$, has Maclaurin's series expansion
\begin{equation}\label{arcsin-series-expansion-unify}
\biggl(\frac{\arcsin t}{t}\biggr)^{m}
=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{Q(m,2k;2)}{\binom{m+2k}{m}}\frac{(2t)^{2k}}{(2k)!},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}\label{Q(m-k)-sum-dfn}
Q(m,k;\alpha)=\sum_{\ell=0}^{k} \binom{m+\ell-1}{m-1} s(m+k-1,m+\ell-1)\biggl(\frac{m+k-\alpha}{2}\biggr)^{\ell}
\end{equation}
for $m,k\in\mathbb{N}$, the constant $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $m+k\ne\alpha$, and the Stirling numbers of the first kind $s(m+k-1,m+\ell-1)$ are generalized by
\begin{equation}\label{1st-stirl-gen-funct}
\frac{[\ln(1+x)]^k}{k!}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty s(n,k)\frac{x^n}{n!},\quad |x|<1.
\end{equation}
For the proofs of Theorem 1 above, please refer to the following papers.

References

1. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **16** (2022), no. 2, 427--466; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
2. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Series expansions of powers of arcsine, closed forms for special values of Bell polynomials, and series representations of generalized logsine functions*, AIMS Mathematics **6** (2021), no. 7, 7494--7517; available online at https://doi.org/10.3934/math.2021438.
3. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.