# Are these new series formulae for $\zeta(2)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

Let $\zeta(n)$ denote the Riemann zeta function defined for positive integers greater than $1$ by its usual infinite series. Thus, $\zeta(2)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}$. Many formulae exist involving $\zeta(2)$, including the Apéry-like fast-converging series:
$$
\zeta (2)=3\sum _{{n=1}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {1}{n^{{2}}{\binom  {2n}{n}}}}.
$$
Recently I have found the following similar-looking series:

> $$
> \zeta (2)=\frac83\sum _{{n=1}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {2^{n-1}}{n^{{2}}{\binom  {2n}{n}}}},
> $$
>   $$
> \zeta (2)=\frac94\sum _{{n=1}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {3^{n-1}}{n^{{2}}{\binom  {2n}{n}}}}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> \zeta (2)=\frac43\sum _{{n=1}}^{{\infty }}{\frac  {4^{n-1}}{n^{{2}}{\binom  {2n}{n}}}}.
> $$

Are these series already known? A quick internet search yields no such results.

---

**EDIT** forgot to add the second series.

Comment: Mathematica knows both.

Comment: We have: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}}=2\arcsin^2 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}$$ You can check your particular cases using this general formula

Comment: To answer the question, no, these results are not new, since the general Taylor series for $\arcsin^2 y$ has been known for a long time

Comment: @YuriyS Thank you for the comment! If you could elaborate on that in the form of an answer I will be happy to accept it

Comment: As a (rather silly) instance of this formula, one may write $$\zeta{2} = \frac{25}{12}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}} \left(\frac{{5}-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n.$$

Answer (score 3):

Please see the following [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383068/finding-the-expansion-of-arcsinz2)
for the proof of the fact

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}}=2\left[\sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} \right]^2$

Just note that in the result given in [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383068/finding-the-expansion-of-arcsinz2), you need to replace $x$ by $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}$ and also make sure that $0 \leq x \leq 4$

Comment: @PTDS can you please elaborate in (much) more detail? I cannot offer the bounty to a "hint"...