# Normalizing a Beta Distribution using infinite series

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series

In order to practice manipulating infinite series, I have been trying to find that normalization constant for the Beta distribution

$$
p(\theta | \alpha, \beta) \propto \theta ^{\alpha - 1} (1 - \theta)^{\beta - 1}
$$

by using the binomial expansion

$$
\theta ^{\alpha - 1} (1 - \theta)^{\beta - 1} = \theta ^{\alpha - 1} \left(\frac{1}{0!} - \frac{(\beta - 1)\theta}{1!} + \frac{(\beta - 1)(\beta - 2)\theta^2}{2!} - ...\right)
$$

$$
= \theta ^{\alpha - 1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\prod_{i = 1}^{n} (\beta - i)}{n!}\theta^n.
$$

and then integrating this expression from $0$ to $1$:

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \theta ^{\alpha - 1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\prod_{i = 1}^{n} (\beta - i)}{n!}\theta^n d\theta = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\prod_{i = 1}^{n} (\beta - i)}{n!}\theta^{\alpha + n - 1} d\theta
$$

$$
= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\prod_{i = 1}^{n} (\beta - i)}{(\alpha + n)n!}.
$$

I need to show that this infinite series is equal to:

$$
B(\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}
$$

During my attempts I have noticed that $\prod_{i = 1}^{n} (\beta - i)$ can be rewritten as

$$
\prod_{i = 1}^{n} (\beta - i) = \frac{\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\beta - n)}
$$

which, assuming series does converge to $B(\alpha, \beta)$, would mean that

$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(\alpha + n)n!\Gamma(\beta - n)} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}.
$$

and could therefore serve as a step in the proof.

I have also tried to find a recurrence expression, to group each even term with its successor to exploit the sign switching, and to decompose the terms into partial fractions, but perhaps because of lack of mathematical maturity, perhaps because I made some mistake I didn't notice, those techniques didn't work. Therefore, any hints would be appreciated.

(I am aware of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251624/problem-deriving-beta-distribution-normalizing-constant) , however the point here is to become better skilled at manipulating infinite series.)

EDIT: Just edited for clarity.

Comment: Where did $\Gamma(\beta)$ go when you substituted the expression for $\prod_i (\beta-i)$ in the series?

Comment: Since it is independent of $n$, we can extract it from the summation and cancel it with its corresponding term in the expression for $B(\alpha, \beta)$, can we not?

Comment: Yes, but I thought you were trying to *show* that the series $=B(\alpha,\beta)$ yet that cancellation seems to be assuming the equality. I think I misread it—it seems you are going the route of “if it holds, it reduces to this new equality, which remains to be shown”, is this so? Sorry for the confusion/noise.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. It is just something that I noticed and that would help guide me in the proof. I will edit for clarity. Thank you!