# Normalization proof of Gamma distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, change-of-variable

I am trying to prove the normalization proof of Gamma distribution, as mentioned in [Problem deriving Beta distribution normalizing constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251624/problem-deriving-beta-distribution-normalizing-constant)

I would like to know the reason of changing variable $x=t\mu$ there. At the beginning, they let $t=x+y$. By their reasoning, $x=(x+y)\mu$, which does not make sense to me.

Comment: You start with the product of gamma integrals over $x$ and $y$ which you know how to do.  You then use a change of variables to a gamma integral over $t=x+y$ which you know how to do and a beta integral over $\mu=\frac{x}{x+y}$ which you want to know how to do.  $\mu$ is simply what proportion of the total is represented by $x$, and so (since $x$ and $y$ are positive) must be between $0$ and $1$

Comment: Thank you. I understand that $E(\mu)=\frac{a}{a+b}$, with $a, b$ are hyper parameters. Is it because $\mu$ is in the integral, we replace $a, b$ with $x, y$?